# Should I skip review-queue items that I've already handled normally?

Tags: support, review

Just now I opened a question, saw something from a new poster that didn't meet guidelines, gave a down-vote and a helpful comment on how to fix. Then I noticed new review items, so I jumped into the review queue and then saw the exact same post.

Only I couldn't change my vote in the queue and I already had a comment. In this case, should I just skip it? Is there any harm in skipping review items like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treat it like any review item: if you have something useful you can do, do that. If you can't, skip it.

There isn't harm in skipping review items — it means the item just gets left there for the next reviewer to encounter and deal with. [It's even a useful tool for avoiding burnout.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232140/152515) (If *everyone* skips it that's a problem, but an unlikely one.) If you're unsure, you can skip.